# Regarding Callback method used for BeginReceive method

Tags: vb.net, sockets, asyncsocket, beginreceive

Following is the callback method that I use in my socket programming at client side for async receiving of data from server:-

```
Public Sub Connect()    
    m_clientSocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    m_clientSocket.Connect(Ip, PortNo)
    If (m_clientSocket.Connected) Then       
        m_clientSocket.BeginReceive(dataBuffer, 0,dataBuffer.Length SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnDataReceived), m_clientSocket)     //here I connect the callback OnDataRecieved
    End If    
End Sub    

Public Sub OnDataRecieved(ByVal async As IAsyncResult)    
    Dim Recieved_Size As Integer = m_clientSocket.EndReceive(async)  
    ' rest of the code ...    
End Sub
```

What my doubt is that when inside "OnDataReceived method" "Received_Size" = 0, should I conclude that the socket has got disconnected? If not, then under what cases should Received_Size be = 0 ?

Why I am asking is that whenever the connected server gets disconnected then "OnDataReceived" method gets called and the resulting "Received_Size" is = 0. But it should be called only when there is some data to be read for the socket, not when connect/disconnect happens, right?

I would really appreciate anyone who would clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b) (emphasis mine):

> If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown
>   method, and all available data has been received, **the EndReceive
>   method will complete immediately and return zero bytes**.

You have a streaming socket, so this is signaling a disconnect.  I suspect that this happens to allow each call to `BeginReceive` to be matched with a call to `EndReceive`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gideon. So, when ever in my callback method (for data receiving) I receive 0 bytes, I can safely assume that the host has got disconnected and I can close my own client socket.
This cleared a lot of my doubts. Thanks once again :)